# Getting undefined for any parameters when hash is specified after query in URL, is this a bug?

Tags: react-router

Recently I ran into an issue pulling query string parameters from a URL that was generated using [Node.js URL API](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html) when using the hashHistory. The URL was generated in a way that looked like the one below.

*http://localhost:7000/?name=value***#/fakepathafterhash**

When attempting to access the query parameter called **name** as shown below it is undefined.

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.location.name !== this.props.name) {
        this.props.dispatch(actions.nameSpecified(nextProps.location.name));
    }
}
```

The interesting thing is that my app is routing to the correct route it's just the query string that is not picked up and shared using the location prop. If I instead alter the URL so that it is in the form below then everything works as I expect and the query string gives me "value" as the value of the **name** parameter.

*http://localhost:7000/***#/fakepathafterhash***?name=value*

Originally I thought this may be a bug in react-router but based on the feedback from one of the maintainers it sounds like they thing that that question is best sorted out here first. So, is this a bug or is it expected behavior?

**UPDATE:** Ah, I just realized that in my case there was an additional question mark and query string being appended to my URL once the page is loaded such as below.

*http://localhost:7000/?name=value#/fakepathafterhash***?_k=431fvt**

I bet this is the cause due to having two question marks in the URL. Now I have to try to find out what is responsible for putting the _k parameter to my query string.

**UPDATE:** Ok, so the [Hash History documentation](http://rackt.org/history/stable/HashHistoryCaveats.html) pointed out a way to override the behavior that seems to be responsible for putting the **_k** parameters in my Query string. Following the directions I was able to to get rid of the second question mark and the generated *queryKey* parameter but unfortunately I'm still experiencing the same issue in that my query parameter **name** is undefined.

Reated discussion:

- https://github.com/rackt/react-router/issues/665
- https://github.com/rackt/react-router/issues/413
- https://github.com/rackt/react-router/issues/1797
- https://github.com/rackt/react-router/issues/1967
- http://rackt.org/history/stable/HashHistoryCaveats.html